# Recursively merging multiple XSLT stylesheets

Tags: xslt

I am looking to merge multiple xslt stylesheets (V1.0) into one stylesheet.

I have already looked at a similar issue posted here.

[Merge multiple xslt stylesheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70143/merge-multiple-xslt-stylesheets/70591#70591)

The answer provided on the post does work but only links imported stylesheets one level in.

Here is the provided answer to this that achieves this.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="xsl:include">
      <xsl:copy-of select="document(@href)/xsl:stylesheet/*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

I have xsl:import references one level down on the imported stylesheets so need to re-curse the imported stylesheets too, otherwise I just get the xsl:import links for the next level down which defeats the object of a single XSLT.

Just creating a single XSLT in the first place isn't an option as they need to be separate to manage content version control easier.

Does anyone how this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you simply replace

```
<xsl:template match="xsl:include">
  <xsl:copy-of select="document(@href)/xsl:stylesheet/*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

with

```
<xsl:template match="xsl:include">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@href)/xsl:stylesheet/*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

However, you say you want to collapse the `xsl:import` declarations as well as xsl:include. Doing that would change the semantics of your code.

(In fact, merging in the xsl:includes can have some minor side-effects as well. It means that templates in the included module come under the influence of attributes such as exclude-result-prefixes in the xsl:stylesheet element of the main module, and loses any such attributes that were present in the included module.)

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  Ignore the xsl:import statement.  I meant to say xsl:include.