# how to use wicket XsltTransformerBehavior when I have multiple .xsl files

Tags: xslt, wicket, xsl-fo

I'm working part of a project that needs to display a .xml file with .xsl files.
Here's part of the code:

```
FILE_PATH = "myxsl.xsl"
...
Label content = new Label("content",xmlContent);
content.setEscapeModelStrings(false);
content.add(new XsltTransformerBehavior(FILE_PATH));    
add(content);
...
```

Currently the page works if I use only one .xsl file. However, because the .xsl files I need to deal with can be really long, they are separated into several components. 
for example, I will have
    mymain.xsl, head.xsl, tables.xsl
the mymain.xsl has inclusion of the other like this

```
<xsl:include href="head.xsl"/>
<xsl:include href="tables.xsl"/>
```

I tried to set FILE_PATH to mymain.xsl, but it didn't work. The program can find mymain.xsl but cannot compile the stylesheet because it cannot find head.xsl and tables.xsl

I've been searching for a long time but still have no clue how to do this. Really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the documentation of XsltTransformerBehavior, and it looks like it doesn't expose the functionality to set a custom URI resolver (which is basically what you want to do).

However, in the case that no-one else has a better solution, I can propose a workaround: Write an XSLT that merges your XSLT files into one file. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70591/347964) for an XSLT that does this. If you're using Maven as build system, you can do this automatically in the generate-resources phase using the [transform goal](http://mojo.codehaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/transform-mojo.html) of  the [Maven XML Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/transform-mojo.html). You can then associate the XsltTransformerBehavior with the single-file XSLT which will be available at run-time.