# Calling xml in xslt using document function

Tags: xml, xslt

I am transforming multiple xml files in multiple folders by applying a single xsl stylesheeet to them.

This xsl needs to use the `document()` function with a URL relative

```
<xsl:variable name="jfsd">
         <xsl:value-of select="document('C:\documents and settings\Desktop\BOPl.xml')//txml" />

  </xsl:variable>
```

But, I am getting the following error:

```
    document('c:\documents and settings\Desktop\BOPl.xml')//txml" />    The function 'document()' is undefined.
```

Comment: Seems you aren't using a compliant XSLT processor. Or is it a processor that is hosted in a server and allowes any internet user to submit a transformation? In this case it is logical that the `document()` function should be forbidden due to security considerations. Finally, you must supply a URL, not a filepath -- something like: `file:///c:/documents and settings/Desktop/BOPl.xml' . Some XSLT processors have a setting that allows the `document()` function -- check the documentation of the XSLT processor.

Comment: It's quite remarkable that given input that refers to a file named BOPl.xml, you are getting an error message that refer to a file named BOPUSCancel.xml.  Are you sure you are describing accurately what you are doing and what result you are getting?

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using, specifically?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the select directly on the variable element.

See my answer on this question: [Transform XML with multiple XSL files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467069/transform-xml-with-multiple-xsl-files/14255985#14255985)

Furthermore I would use relative urls to the document instead of hard-coded fixed url which is OS dependent.