# Append context of one XML to another with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, maven, pom.xml

I have a problem. I would like to join context of two XML files into one. And this with help of xslt-generator-maven-plugin in MAVEN project (POM) and XSL.

I have pom configured like:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>net.sf.xsltmp</groupId>
<artifactId>xslt-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.7</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>transform-contex</id>
<goals>
<goal>many-to-one</goal>
</goals>
<configuration>
<srcDir>src/main/webapp/META-INF/</srcDir>
<srcIncludes>**/*context.xml</srcIncludes>
<xslTemplate>src/main/webapp/Temp.xsl</xslTemplate>
<destFile>${project.build.directory}/contextNEW.xml</destFile>
</configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

I have first file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context debug="0" reloadable="true" >
    <Resourcen name="jdbc/ChiDS"
               auth="Container" 
               type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               ...
</Context>
```

and second like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Context>
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm"
           pathname="webapps/${application.name}/WEB-INF/users.xml"/>
 </Context>
```

and would like to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context debug="0" reloadable="true" >  
<Resourcen name="jdbc/ChiDS"
               auth="Container" 
               type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               ...
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm"
       pathname="webapps/${application.name}/WEB-INF/users.xml"/> 
</Context>
```

So I would append second XML to first. I need to create a correct TEMP.xsl file.

I "need" to use following:

- xslt-generator-maven-plugin

I tried this but tokenize is an problem.

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="source-file-names" />
<xsl:variable name="names-sequence" select="tokenize($source-file-names,'\|')" />
<xsl:variable name="cfg-files" select="document($names-sequence)" />
```

Any clue? I have tried several thing but didn't solve this.

Thanks for help.

I have tried with this XSL (i fixed the token issue) but no success:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="source-file-names" />
<xsl:variable name="names-sequence" select="fn:tokenize($source-file-names,'\|')" />
<xsl:variable name="cfg-files" select="document($names-sequence)" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$cfg-files/*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I have looked at this sample : https://github.com/ivos/xslt-generator-maven-plugin/issues/1
But no success on my side.

Any help is welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a third xml document that contains the other xml files that you want to join.
I think this is helpful: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipcombxslt/

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how many files there are and what the context will be. I can have like this: #1 file located at ${project.build.directory}/classes/rebel.xml
#2 file located at ${project.build.directory}/gis-ol/WEB-INF/classes/rebel.xml
#3 file located at ${project.build.directory}/war/work/pt.xlm.gir/datageo/WEB-INF/classes/rebel.xml  So also the names are the same.

Comment: I am unsure that xsl transformation can be that advanced/complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at my example here where I combined two xml files using xslt variable document load. You can find it here: [Transform XML with multiple XSL files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467069/transform-xml-with-multiple-xsl-files/14255985#14255985)